# id for Table identification

Tags: javascript, html

I have several tables in my HTML page:

```
<body>
    <h1>Array to Table</h1>
 <div class="test">  
    <table id="tableA" name="tableA" border="1" class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Portugues</th>
            <th>English</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
     <br><br>
     Portugues: <input type="text" name="port" id="port">
     English: <input type="text" name="engl" id="engl"><br><br>
     <button id="btnadd" onclick="btnAddRow()">Add Row</button>
<!-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------- -->   

     <table id="tableB" name="tableB" border="1" class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>test1</th>
            <th>test2</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>      
</body>
```

My Javascript code:

```
var x =1;
function btnAddRow()
{
    var portV = document.getElementById('port').value;
    var englV = document.getElementById('engl').value;    

    var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];

    console.log(table);

    var newRow = table.insertRow(x);

    var cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);

    cell1.innerHTML = portV;
    cell2.innerHTML = englV;

    x = x + 1;

}
```

the [0] or [1] will identify the first or the second table.

```
var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
```

There is no way to identify them using their appropriate id's? tableA or tableB ? If yes, what would be the coding?

Comment: `document.getElementById('tableA')`?

Comment: [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

Comment: You're already using `getElementById`, just use that

Comment: But mind ID has to be unique unless you get 1st only, in case you may have repeated ID, name should work better, but getElementByName returns Array, so if you switch unique IDs to Names, you will have to use 1st index document.getElementByName('tableA')[0]

Comment: I tried, it didn't work. I'll try again

Answer (score 0):

```js
const tables = document.querySelectorAll('table');

console.log(tables[0].id, tables[1].id, tables[2].id);

// From a loop
tables.forEach((table)=> {
  console.log(table.id);
});

const table1 = document.querySelector('#tableA')
const table2 = document.querySelector('#tableB')
const table3 = document.querySelector('#tableC')

console.log(table1.id, table2.id, table3.id);
```

```html
 <table id="tableA" name="tableA" border="1" class="table">
   <tr>
     <th>Portugues</th>
     <th>English</th>
   </tr>
 </table>
 
  <table id="tableB" name="tableB" border="1" class="table">
   <tr>
     <th>Portugues</th>
     <th>English</th>
   </tr>
 </table>
 
  <table id="tableC" name="tableC" border="1" class="table">
   <tr>
     <th>Portugues</th>
     <th>English</th>
   </tr>
 </table>
```